# go to the next div holder when user clicks on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gallery, I'd like to close the active holder div and go to the next one when user clicks on it:

The problem is, div holder with text 1 is not closing and going to the next holder. What is the problem with my JS?

```js
$(document).on("click", ".holder", function() {
  slideSwitch();
});

var ss=0;
function slideSwitch() {
  alert("click holder go to next next holder");

  var gallery = $('#slideshow'),
    active = gallery.find('.holder'),
    next;

  var number = $(".holder").length;

  if (active.next().length) {
    if (ss < number) {
      next = active.next();
ss++;
    }
  }

  active.hide();
  next.show();

}
```

```css
.holder {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=slideshow>
  <div class='holder active'>
    text 1
  </div>

  <div class='holder'>
    text 2
  </div>

  <div class='holder'>
    text 3
  </div>

  <div class='holder'>
    text 4
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oavnz8y2/1/

Comment: what should happen if you click on 'text 4' div?

Comment: @samnupel hide div slideshow.

Comment: Where is `ss` defined?

Comment: Check the console. You have at least one error

Comment: @StaticBeagle ss is global, I forget to add it here, and ss++ each next call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on( "click", ".holder", function() {
    slideSwitch();
});

function slideSwitch() {
  var current = $('#slideshow .active');
  current.removeClass('active');
  if (current.next().length) {
      current.next().addClass('active');
  } else {
      $('#slideshow').hide();
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oavnz8y2/8/

Comment: it is amazing, the only problem is that it never goes to the `else {` do you know why? I need to know when gallery ends to call another function in my real project. I add an alert inside else and it will not show.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".holder", function() {
    slideSwitch();
});


function slideSwitch() {

    var active = $('#slideshow .holder.active');
    var index = $('#slideshow > div').index(active);

    if(index == 3)
        index = 0;
    else index++;

    active.removeClass('active');

    $('#slideshow').children().eq(index).addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be more readable and easy. You can try this one:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".holder", function() {
    slideSwitch($(this));
});

function slideSwitch(e) {
  if(e.index() < $('.holder').length) {
    e.hide();
    e.next().show();
  };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bg3qs9eo/1/

Answer (score 0):

This line is srange

```
 active = gallery.find('.holder'),
```

It gives you several elements, so you cant do `.next()`
You have to add a class on your active holder, then look the next holder from the active holder.

You have to remove the active class from the active holder and add it to the next one.

Here is what i would simply do. When you click on a holder, it closes this holder and show the previous holder who is no longer active :

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $('.holder:not(.active)').click(function(e){
    $('.holder.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.holder{ display:block; cursor: pointer;  border:1px solid black; margin:0.5rem auto;}
.holder.active{  display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=slideshow>
      <div class='holder'>text 1</div>
      <div class='holder'>text 2</div>
      <div class='holder'>text 3</div>
      <div class='holder'>text 4</div>
</div>
```